# How does indesign calculate itemtransform

Tags: adobe, adobe-indesign

For a project im working on i need to know how indesign calculates/generate itemtransform

when the element is not rotated the itemtransform = "1 0 0 1 0 0"
then when I rotate the element 90deg then the itemtransform = "1 -0.5 0.5 1 somecordinate someothercordinate"

open indesign >

new Document >

place an rectangle for example >

save as "enter_name_here".idml >

change the name to "enter_name_here".zip >

extract the files to folder >

open Spreads/spread_ud7.xml in notepad++ and find the itemtransform

now go back to indesign, rotate the rectangle and do the above again, then look at the itemtransform how is that calculated in indesign?

why is that and how is it done if have look in almost every documentation but could not find a clear awnser

anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Find some info inside this PDF:
https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/indesign/cs55-docs/IDML/idml-specification.pdf

i.e. on page 97